# Check if signal is on SIG_DFL or SIG_IGN?

Tags: c, sockets, signals, default, asyncsocket

I am programming a UDP non-blocking socket using SIGIO to read bytes from the receive buffer. In my current setup, I have a client sending periodic messages to the server with a 5 second delay in between sends. However, there is a point in the code where I have to set the default SIG_DFL (or SIG_IGN) to ignore/cancel the pending signals on SIGIO, and re-enable them later. However, what I'm looking for is a sort of `signalisset` or `signalisignore` function that returns an `int` 0 or 1 for whether the signal is ignored or something. I tried implementing it myself using `raise(SIGIO)` and then checking whether a global `volatile` variable has changed value but that did not work.

Thanks!

Comment: You mean, [`(!sigaction(SIGIO, NULL, &act) && act.sa_handler != SIG_DFL && act.sa_handler != SIG_IGN)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)? Don't use `signal()`.

Comment: But, you do realize you can use [`sigprocmask()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigprocmask.2.html) to block the signal, then use [`sigtimedwait()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigtimedwait.2.html) with a zero timeout to consume any pending signals before unblocking them?

Comment: @NominalAnimal I am blocking the signal by setting the mask in the sigaction struct, but I did not know about the `sigtimedwait`.

Comment: The `sa_mask` field in the `struct sigaction` only blocks signals during the execution of that particular handler. You can use `sigprocmask()` to block signal delivery altogether. Do note that `SIGIO` is not queued, so at most one can be pending at any time.

Comment: @NominalAnimal but why would I want to block all signals when the SIGIO handler is not executing?

Comment: You wrote: *"I am blocking the signal by setting the mask in the sigaction struct."* I responded that that only blocks the signal during the signal handler execution. `sigprocmask()` does not block all signals, it controls which signals are blocked. Rather than set the signal handler to `SIG_IGN`, you can simply block it. To reinstate it, you unblock the signal. The signal can become pending while blocking. To avoid having it delivered immediately when unblocked, you can "receive" it using `sigtimedwait()` just before unblocking it.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Okay, here's my situation. I have a SIGIO activating when the client sends a message to me. However, the messages are approx. 1024 bursts of 1024-byte packets (the client sends 1024 packets all at once). I want the server to trigger on SIGIO on the first packet, and in the handler I have a `while` loop that goes through all the rest of the 1024-1 packets and reads them (for this current run). However, I have several runs of these 1024 packet sends, and they are separated by 5 seconds. So I want the first packet to trigger the SIGIO, the `while` empties the buffer, and

Comment: @NominalAnimal **inside the** signal handler I cancel the one SIGIO pending signal that might be caused from the remaining 1024-1 packets on the first run, and re-enable SIGIO for the next run first packet (in 5 secs).

Comment: I would personally just use a dedicated thread in a blocking receive in that scenario, and not bother with async I/O at all.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Ugh really? Guess I better rewrite stuff